# Time module in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

I'm trying to create an app and I have a question about Time in rails.
My app has two models, a user and a post.
I want to limit the user to only create one post per day. 
I did a validation on Time.now but I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do because a user might change the date on his machine and bypass the validation.

How do I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time is not taken from user's machine, but rather from the server you run your website on. So you have nothing to worry about. On a side note: it's better to use Time.current instead of Time.now as it also considers the timezones.